# Remove certain return characters from tab-separated values file

Tags: python, postgresql

I've got a problem at work that requires me to insheet some MASSIVE tab-separated values files (think 8-15 GB .txt files) into my PostgreSQL DB, but I've run into a problem with the way the data was formatted in the first place. Basically, the way we are given the data (and unfortunately we cannot get the data in a better format), there are some backslashes that appear and cause a return/new line.

So, there are lines (rows of data, tab-delim) that get chopped up into multiple lines, where the last character of line n is a \ , and the first character of line n+1 is a tab. Usually line n will be broken up into 1-3 additional lines (e.g. line n ends in a "\", lines n+1 and n+2 start with a tab and end with a "\", and line n+3 starts with a tab).

I need to write a script that can work with these huge files (this will run on a linux server with 192 GB of RAM) to look for the lines that begin with a tab, and then remove the return (and "\" wherever it exists) and save the text file.

To recap, the customer's logging program splits the original line N into lines n, n+1, and sometimes n+2 and n+3 (depending on how many \ characters appear in line N), and I need to write a python script to recreate the original line N.

Comment: Post a small sample with anything sensitive redacted. Expected input and output are a good way to illustrate this kind of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on @user665637's good answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re, sys

pat_incomplete = re.compile(r'\\\s*$')
pat_indented = re.compile(r'^\t')

try:
    _, fname_in, fname_out = sys.argv
except ValueError:
    print("Usage: python line_joiner.py <input_filename> <output_filename>")
    sys.exit(1)

with open(fname_in) as in_f, open(fname_out, "w") as out_f:
    lines = iter(in_f)
    try:
        line = next(lines)
        s = pat_incomplete.sub('', line)
    except StopIteration:
        print("Input file did not contain any data")
        sys.exit(2)

    for line in lines:
        line = pat_incomplete.sub('', line)
        if pat_indented.match(line):
            s += pat_indented.sub('',line)
        else:
            out_f.write(s)
            s = line
    out_f.write(s)
```

Changes:

- Uses "raw strings" for the regular expressions, which are easier to read.
- Takes an output filename from the command-line arguments and writes to that file.  Prints a message and exits if the user provides the wrong number of arguments.  When we unpack `sys.argv` to get the arguments, we use the convention of using the variable name `_` for parts we don't care about.
- Does not strip line endings, so the output file will have the same sort of line-endings as the input file.  (When joining lines, of course it strips the line endings to do the join.)
- Does not filter out blank lines from the input.  It's a little bit tricky, but by making an iterator and calling `next()` on it, it gets the first input line before starting the loop; thus `s` starts out with a valid value instead of `None`, and we don't have to test it each time to see whether to print it or not.  The original `if lastLine:` test, on an input line that was stripped, would not only protect against the initial `None` value of `lastLine` but would also filter out any blank lines from the input.
- If you have to use this with Python 3.0 or Python 2.6, you can't have a `with` statement that does two `open()` calls; but you can just turn it into two nested `with` statements, each of which does a single `open()`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! You have saved me tons of time. Let me know if there is anything I can do for you (charity you'd like something donated to? etc)!

Comment: You're welcome!  If you really want to you could give another small donation to the EFF, but please don't feel you must.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re,sys

lastLine = None
incomplete = re.compile("\\\\+$")
indented = re.compile("^\\t")

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = incomplete.sub("", line)
    if indented.match(line):
        lastLine += indented.sub("",line)
    else:
        if lastLine:
            print lastLine
            lastLine = None
        lastLine = line

print lastLine
```

Basically, i'm ignoring the \ at the end since the tab on the next line tells you that it's a continuation anyways.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! As promised, $10 given to the EFF (not quite sure how to directly post an image in the comments, so here's a link):

[link](http://i.imgur.com/V2chc.png)

Now, this code seems like it would work, but how would I get it to read in a text file and save a corrected text file. In other words, I would imagine using it with the command:

Comment: <continued...>                   `python cleanData.py uglyData.tsv`      which would then save the cleaned data in a text file named uglyData-CLEAN.tsv or something along those lines?

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  I made a few tweaks to it and posted my own version, but full credit to the source.

Comment: to run it, save the file as, say cleanData.py then run: python cleanData.py myfile.tsv > clean.tsv'. I'm assuming you're on a unix type platform to be able to do the stdout redirect to a file. if on windows, tweak the python script to write to a file instead of printing to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the "\n" sequence by nothing :

```
In [20]: a="blabla\tblabla\tblabla\\\n\tblabla\tblabla"

In [21]: print(a)
blabla  blabla  blabla\
    blabla  blabla

In [22]: a=a.replace('\\\n', '')

In [23]: print(a)
blabla  blabla  blabla  blabla  blabla
```

:)

Comment: As promised, $10 given to the EFF:

Comment: @user1514979: If the answer was helpful, you should upvote or accept it. Donation is nice but cannot replace customs around here.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  He has input lines in a specific format that need to be merged, and the input files are huge so the need to be read line-by-line.